# Rails: determining whether to use SSL for url() in CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, sass

Suppose I had a file `fonts.css.scss` with the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Play';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('Play-Bold'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/play/v3/aBiGxW3iLixHo08CkkYT9gLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff') format('woff');
}
```

If my application were to be requested via SSL, the font file above would still be requested insecurely, which many browsers don't like and will complain about.

I tried renaming the file to `font.css.erb`, and then trying to use `request.ssl?` to determine whether to use http or https, but apparently `request` is undefined in assets.

So, what can I change to have the font loaded over SSL if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that css files in the assets directory are compiled into static assets, but you need that snippet of css to be dynamic. If that's the only url you're worried about, you could just put it into your view. If there's lots of url's referenced in your css you could make two different css files, one https friendly and one not. Then dynamically decide which file to load from your view.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same conclusion I've arrived at now that I've taken a break and have a clearer head :).  I decided to just hard-code the `https://` since that will always work and the extra overhead of a SSL call will be minuscule for this particular request.